# Win32_Account class strange behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, wmi, user-accounts

Im doing a little Computer-Information tool. Right now I am doing the user accounts. I fill a combobox with the available users.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mosAccounts = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Account");

        foreach (ManagementObject moUA in mosAccounts.Get())
        {
            comboBox4.Items.Add(moUA["Name"].ToString());
        }
```

Then I display them:

```
private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher mosAccounts = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Account");

        foreach (ManagementObject moUA in mosAccounts.Get())
        {
            lblDescriptionUA.Text = "Description: " + moUA["Description"].ToString();

            if (moUA["Domain"] != null)
            {
                lblDomain.Text = "Domain: " + moUA["Domain"].ToString();
            }

            else
                lblDomain.Text = "Domain: Not Available";

            if (moUA["InstallDate"] != null)
            {
                lblInstallDateUA.Text = "Install Date: " + moUA["InstallDate"].ToString();
            }

            else
                lblInstallDateUA.Text = "Install Date: Not Available";

            lblLocalAccount.Text = "Local Account: " + moUA["LocalAccount"].ToString();

            if (moUA["SID"] != null)
            {
                lblSID.Text = "SID: " + moUA["SID"].ToString();
            }

            else
                lblSID.Text = "SID: Not Available";

            if (moUA["SIDType"] != null)
            {
                lblSIDType.Text = "SID Type: " + moUA["SIDType"];
            }

            else
                lblSIDType.Text = "SID Type: Not Available";

            if (moUA["Status"] != null)
            {
                lblStatusUA.Text = "Status: " + moUA["Status"].ToString();
            }

            else
                lblStatusUA.Text = "Status: Not Available";
        }
    }
```

But everytime I select a user from the combobox, the labels are going insane, showing so much information ,switching it. It's like they are showing information about all users in a row. Is there something I am missing?

Additional Information: I am at work. There are a lot of domain users. The combobox shows them all. Mybe its because all of the domain users. I made an option to only display local users, but same problem with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But everytime I select a user from the combobox, the labels are going insane, showing so much information ,switching it. It's like they are showing information about all users in a row.

Yes - because that's *exactly* what your code says to do:

```
// Every time you select a user...
private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Find all the information about all users...
    ManagementObjectSearcher mosAccounts =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Account");

    // Iterate over all those users and display it
    foreach (ManagementObject moUA in mosAccounts.Get())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The code is doing exactly what you asked it to. Now, *why* have you hooked up an event handler like that? Think about what you *actually* want to achieve when the selected index changes. Did you actually want to find just the *single* selected user? If so, presumably you just need to change the query you're using in `ManagementObjectSearcher`, and then find the single result instead of iterating over all results.